# AngularJS without framework

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, frameworks, database-connection

I'm a newbie to AngularJS, and I've created an web application by using it.

I would like to know whether it is possible to create a Web application in AngularJS with database connectivity and without using any framework (like Ruby on Rails or PHP or any other)?

Comment: Huh? You need something to run serverside. That could be a framework, or hand written code in pretty much any language you like (including javascript with nodejs), but something has to interact with the database - you cant do that directly in client side code (or if it is technically possible, it would be a very bad idea)

Comment: In PHP terms, you can avoid, say, Slim and Symfony, but you still need a server-side language. You can indeed use pHP on its own if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for getting me understand guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AngularJS to do as little or as much as you would like on your web application. However AngularJS is a client side scripting language, if you need to communicate with a database you will need a server side language in order to do this. You ask if you are able to do this without "frameworks" and the answer if yes, but you cannot do it without a physical language like Ruby or PHP.

If you are looking for a lightweight framework to do simple REST requests for your AngularJS application I would highly recommend a ruby framework called [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) it takes minutes to set up, if you would want to connect to a database like MySQL or PostgreSQL then I would also suggest using [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) as your ORM. Alternatively you can create your own PHP script to avoid the use of a framework.